# Compile ChromeDriver on ARM

Tags: c++, arm, chromium, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi3

I need to use Selenium with ChromeDriver on ARMv7 Raspberry Pi 3 (Firefox does not fit in my project), but as there are only [pre-compiled binaries](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) for x86 and x64, I tried to compile it from the [source code](https://github.com/scheib/chromium/tree/master/chrome/test/chromedriver) on my own...

But as the Chromium Project uses a lot of tools that I'm not familiar with to compile the source,  I couldn't even start the process.

I had searched for hours on the internet how to compile it for ARM family but I couldn't find any tutorial or even a successful story about it.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is this 'doable'?
2. Does anyone have any idea of what I can do?

Comment: If you want to compile chromium on ARM, google it and you get https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-do-i-cross-compile-chromium-for-arm

Comment: Actually, I'm talking about just ChromeDriver, but I appreciate your comment and reference.

Comment: Any luck ? I'm looking for v.2.33 but can't find it anywhere :-/

Comment: Look like a dead end... :( Tried to do the same for a while, giving up on the rpi for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### web browser - WebDriver support

> Web browser that aims to build a safer, faster, and more stable internet browsing experience.

This package provides a bridge between the browser component and the selenium automatic webdriver.

Package: [chromium-driver for armhf](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/chromium-driver)

Comment: Works flawlessly on Beaglebone black with Debian 10. Perfect answer!

Comment: sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver

Answer (score 23):

### arm64, arm7l, win32-arm64 [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) Unofficial Chromedrivers

https://github.com/electron/electron/releases

---

- **100.0.4896.143** | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v18.2.1/chromedriver-v18.2.1-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v18.2.1/chromedriver-v18.2.1-linux-armv7l.zip) | [Win32-Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v18.2.1/chromedriver-v18.2.1-win32-arm64.zip) (2022-03-30)
- **98.0.4706.0** | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v17.0.0-beta.2/chromedriver-v17.0.0-beta.2-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v17.0.0-beta.2/chromedriver-v17.0.0-beta.2-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **96.0.4664.110** | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v16.0.6/chromedriver-v16.0.6-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v16.0.6/chromedriver-v16.0.6-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **94.0.4606.81** | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v15.3.4/chromedriver-v15.3.4-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v15.3.4/chromedriver-v15.3.4-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **93.0.4577.82** | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v14.2.3/chromedriver-v14.2.3-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v14.2.3/chromedriver-v14.2.3-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **92.0.4511.0**   | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v14.0.0-beta.1/chromedriver-v14.0.0-beta.1-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v14.0.0-beta.1/chromedriver-v14.0.0-beta.1-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **91.0.4472.69**  | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v13.0.1/chromedriver-v13.0.1-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v13.0.1/chromedriver-v13.0.1-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **89.0.4389.128** | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v12.0.9/chromedriver-v12.0.9-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v12.0.9/chromedriver-v12.0.9-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **87.0.4280.141** | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v11.2.3/chromedriver-v11.2.3-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v11.2.3/chromedriver-v11.2.3-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **86.0.4234.0**   | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v11.0.0-beta.7/chromedriver-v11.0.0-beta.7-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v11.0.0-beta.7/chromedriver-v11.0.0-beta.7-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **85.0.4183.98**  | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v10.1.2/chromedriver-v10.1.2-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v10.1.2/chromedriver-v10.1.2-linux-armv7l.zip) | (Sep 2020 Stable)
- **83.0.4102.3**   | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.0.0-beta.15/chromedriver-v9.0.0-beta.15-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.0.0-beta.15/chromedriver-v9.0.0-beta.15-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **82.0.4085.27**  | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.0.0-beta.14/chromedriver-v9.0.0-beta.14-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v9.0.0-beta.14/chromedriver-v9.0.0-beta.14-linux-armv7l.zip) | ([Skipped](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2020/03/chrome-and-chrome-os-release-updates.html))
- **80.0.3987.163** | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v8.2.1/chromedriver-v8.2.1-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v8.2.1/chromedriver-v8.2.1-linux-armv7l.zip) | (Feb 2020 Stable)
- **78.0.3866.0**   | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v7.0.0-beta.2/chromedriver-v7.0.0-beta.2-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v7.0.0-beta.2/chromedriver-v7.0.0-beta.2-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **76.0.3809.126** | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v6.0.3/chromedriver-v6.0.3-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v6.0.3/chromedriver-v6.0.3-linux-armv7l.zip) | (Aug 2019 Stable)
- **2.45**          | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v5.0.10/chromedriver-v5.0.10-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v5.0.10/chromedriver-v5.0.10-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **2.40.672629**   | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v4.2.9/chromedriver-v4.2.9-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v4.2.9/chromedriver-v4.2.9-linux-armv7l.zip)
- **2.36**          | [Arm64](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v3.1.13/chromedriver-v3.1.13-linux-arm64.zip) | [Arm7l](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v3.1.13/chromedriver-v3.1.13-linux-armv7l.zip)

Comment: what's the arm version of chromedriver for chromium=74.0.3729.157 ?

Comment: @Eunito It appears electron never made a version for chromium=74.0.3729.157. Release [electron v5.0.1](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v5.0.1) says, "Updated Chromium to 73.0.3683.121. #18001". Then their next release after it [electron v6.0.0-beta.2](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v6.0.0-beta.2) says, "Updated Chromium to 76.0.3783.1. #18116". So it appears they skipped 74.x altogether. I feel a bit out of luck because my raspberry pi running debian seems to only support 74.x as the latest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I've been searching for ever to find a compatible version of the driver!

Comment: @slhck I download the windows or linux executable and run that, the first thing it prints out is the chromedriver version. If you want to automate that I suppose you have to automatically download the latest release linux executable, run that and pipe out the output to a text file. Never tried it thought.

Comment: Hello. Where can I find 84.0.4147.141?

Comment: I am wondering how they build it. I would like to simply do it on my own machine seeing that they skipped Chromedriver 95, but that is what is available on Raspbian currently.

Comment: you can download new versions here: https://github.com/electron/electron/releases?after=v7.1.5

Comment: sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver