# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/ec2-user/Desktop/chromedriver' error using Chromedriver in AWS EC2 ARM flavour machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I have an EC2 machine from AWS with ARM flavour. I installed Python 3, and then used `pip3` to install Selenium. I then downloaded the Linux version of chrome driver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.20/), unzipped it and kept the `chromedriver` file in Desktop. When I try to run code like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ec2-user/Desktop/chromedriver')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    creationflags=self.creationflags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/ec2-user/Desktop/chromedriver'
```

Any idea how to fix this? May be a different combination of Linux flavour and chrome driver from somewhere else?

Comment: You need a version of chromedriver compiled for ARM. I don't see one at the link you posted. You might look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732822/compile-chromedriver-on-arm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/ec2-user/Desktop/chromedriver'
```

...implies that you are using an incorrect format of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) executable.

---

### Deep Dive

As you are using AWS EC2 ARM flavour you need to use the either **ARM64** or **ARM7** variant of *ChromeDriver*.

Additionally, you seem to have downloaded [ChromeDriver v100.x](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.20/) where as the latest version of [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) is ***Chrome Version 99.0.4844.84***

[image: Chrome Version 99.0.4844.84]

and you need the matching version of *ChromeDriver* as per the installed version of *Google Chrome* within the system.

---

### Solution

As *`@Mark B`* pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626728/chromedriver-not-working-properly-in-aws-ec2-arm-flavour-machine#comment126593141_71626728) you need to download the matching version of *ChromeDriver* as per the discussion [Compile ChromeDriver on ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732822/compile-chromedriver-on-arm)